# An algorithm to remove the least amount of numbers in the list in increasing and decreasing order?

Tags: algorithm, list, analysis, puzzle

Consider the following numbers:

9,44,32,12,7,45,31,98,35,37,41,8,20,27,83,64,61,28,39,93,29,92,17,13,14,55,21,66,72,23,73,99,1,2,88,77,3,65,83,84,62,5,11,74,68,76,78,67,75,69,70,22,71,24,25,26.

I try to implement an algorithm to remove the least amount of numbers in the list to make the sequence

a) increasing order
b) decreasing order

I already tried with the shortest and longest subsecuence. Dont want the code, only the explanation or a pseudo code,i can't understand how to solve the problem thanks!

Comment: What does "least amount of numbers" mean?  Are you saying "remove the smallest quantity of items to make the sequence strictly monotonic"?

Comment: yes, remove the few or smallest quantity of items to make a sequence on increasing order and decreasing order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it has already been mentioned, I will add my 2 cents. Most probably this will be asked in interview in those circumstances, the running time(efficiency) is a major concern. So the same problem can be tackled with many algorithms depending on the time they take to execute.
The best known algorithm is of order O(nlogn). Other important one can like Dynamic programming paradigm can also be applied to yield a solution of O(n^2).

[O(n^2) here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-3-longest-increasing-subsequence/)

[O(nlogn) here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a lightly camouflaged [*Longest increasing (decreasing) subsequence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem. The algorithm to solving your problem is as follows:

- Find the longest increasing (decreasing) subsequence in the array
- Remove all elements that do not belong to the longest increasing subsequence.

Since the increasing/decreasing subsequence is longest, the amount of numbers that you will remove is the smallest.

Wikipedia article has a nice pseudocode for solving the LIS/LDS problem. You can substitute binary search for a linear one unless the original sequence is 1000+ elements long.

Comment: If by "lightly camouflaged" you mean "extremely poorly worded" then I would agree.

Comment: @mbratch I've seen this problem worded in several ways in programming competitions. One of them sounded like this: "You are given the titles of books on a shelf the way they are ordered now. What is the smallest number of books that need to be moved in order to alphabetize the titles?"

Comment: @winstonsmith Give it a try, and see how it works. If it works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would indicate that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: But in your answer you said remove all the others; But removing one number in a subsequence might yield an even longer subsequence. Isn't this more a question of permutation?